# After deserialisation object references seem to be different

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, datacontractserializer, pass-by-reference

I have a strange problem when serialising custom data objects via DataContracts and restoring them. I have the following class in which the problem occurs:

```
[DataContract]
public class ProjectManager
{
    // list of projects
    [DataMember]
    public List<Project> ProjectList { get; set; }

    // active project
    [DataMember]
    public Project ActiveProject { get; set; }

    // instance variable
    [DataMember]
    private static ProjectManager instance = null;
```

ActiveProject saves a reference to one object from ProjectList. The problem is that in one case the reference saved in ActiveProject seems not to be equal to the reference in the ProjectList, though there is only one in the list. If I change my ActiveProject, my object in ProjectList is not changed.

This problem occurs ONLY after deserialising data and I don't know what I can do to prevent this error from happening. Is this behaviour possible or must there be any crossreferences in my code that I didn't find yet?

Comment: Can you override `Equals` on `Project`?

Comment: `Is this behaviour possible` yes when you deserialize an object you have a different instance of it.

Comment: I did and made a foreach check of the list against `ActiveProject` just after deserialisation. It returned a "true", so the error must be anywhere else in my code. Damn Tombstoning ... thx for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually deserialization does not take care of 2 objects referencing the same objects. Instead it may create a new object at each reference location.

Try binary serialization / deserialization.

If it still fails, you can create your own serialization, and create an object reference list. As soon as you serialize an object with a reference, that you already stored before (serialized before) then you could add a special tag, and so you would be able to rebuild the reference to the same object during deserialization.

But that is the next thing I plan to add to my serialization, so.. time for custom serialization may be too long. Hopefully binary serialization is sufficient

Another workaround would be to work with a list and to have an integer (refering to the correct index number) instead of a second reference. Or build any other variable that helps you to rebuild double-references

Comment: Deserialization means reading some bytes from a stream an creating an object. The *reference* will never be the same even that all properties/fields are the same. (even with binary serialization)

Comment: @I4V you are right when comparing original object with a  deserialized serialized same object, but I think the problem here is that a serialized class contains more than one reference to the same object, and deserialized, the multiple references are each pointing to individual objects. (so the object references among the variables of the serialized class do change) C.A->D  C.B->D  ..deserialize(serialize(C)).. C.A->D  C.B->D'

Comment: I did some testing: I deserialized the data and compared them. The created objects seemed to be equal. So I changed one object and compared again. Now the objects weren't equal. There are two unique individual objects present after deserialization.

Comment: I finally solved the problem by using an integer as index reference to the correct object in the list. After deserialization I assigned the object to ActiveProject. Works!

Answer (score 1):

DataContractSerializer supports preserving object references; see the `preserveObjectReferences` constructor parameter [in this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa344262.aspx). You may need to change the way you're creating your serializer to support this.

Comment: Seems pretty like what I am looking for, but a bit hard to implement for a beginner.